# Как создать элемент присвоить ему input.value и добавить в другой элемент

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, есть задачка: Реализовать добавление комментариев на "стену". Каждый комментарий должен содержаться в блочном элементе. Для добавления комментария на странице должно находится поле для ввода текста и кнопка добавления. Новый комментарий добавляется вниз списка комментариев.
У меня не получается вывести.

```js
function test() {

  var element = document.getElementById('text');
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

  var p = document.createElement('p');
  var br = document.createElement('br');
  var string = element.value;
  element.innerHTML = string;
  console.log(string);
  el.appendChild(br);
  el.appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="add" onclick="test()">

<div>

</div>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Полагаю, что вам нужно достать из массива элементов div элемент по индексу 0, и в него уже вставлять)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Описание в комментариях

```js
var element = document.getElementById('text');
/* не хватало индекса элемента*/
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
/*не надо создавать кучу элементов можно один и его потом клонировать*/
var p = document.createElement('p');

function test() {
  /*когда срабатывает функция  клонируем "р"*/
  var par = p.cloneNode(true);
  /* присваиваем ему значение  input*/
  par.innerHTML = element.value;
  /* и уже вставляем в div*/
  el.appendChild(par);
  /*очищаем поле ввода*/
  element.value = '';
}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="add" onclick="test()">

<div>

</div>
```

Comment: А чем клонирование элемента лучше, чем создание нового?

Comment: Qwertiy,  Щас и не вспомню подробностей, но когда изучал, читал, запомнил, что клонировать лучше чем создавать...

Answer (score 0):

не `element.innerHTML = string`, а `p.innerHTML = string`